# Type 'any[]' is not assignable to type 'never[]'. Type 'any' is not assignable to type 'never'.ngtsc(2322)

Tags: angular

I use in:

```
NgxTypeAheadComponent.taList: never[]
```

when i init this varable like this:

html:

```
<input [taList]="users">
```

ts:

```
@Input() users: any[] = [];
```

i get this error:

```
Type 'any[]' is not assignable to type 'never[]'. 
Type 'any' is not assignable to type 'never'.ngtsc(2322)
```

how i fix this problem?

Answer (score 1):

As the error log says the types are not matching and therefore have to be changed both in never or both in any type. However I recommend to use the explicit datatype whenever possible.

Answer (score 0):

you are using a very old component with a pretty new version of typescript.
Sources of a component contain this piece of code `taList = [];`, which is inferred as `never[]`. this means that basically there should be no values in this array.

It is either the library should be updated or you shouldn't be using that old component.

If it is necessary to use exactly this component you could try to remove type assertions at all like this:

```
[taList]="$any(users)"
```